# Is this argument valid? $ \left(P\supset Q\right), \sim Q \to \;\sim \!P $

Tags: logic

This is presented as an example of a valid argument. So, I think the author made a mistake and used the super-set symbol when he meant to use the subset symbol. I think the argument should read:

$ P $ is a subset of $ Q $. $ x $ is not in $ Q $. Therefore $ x $ is not in $ P $.

Which makes sense to me.

Instead it reads:

$ P $ is a super-set of $ Q $...

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with sets.

Some texts use the $\supset$ symbol as the logical symbol for material implication. Most texts use $\to$ instead

Confusingly, this text does use $\to$ … but seems to use it differently! I think they use $\to$ here for logical implication … most texts typically use something like $\vDash$ or $\implies$. I must say that I have never seen the $\to$ used as such so that is really confusing!

Anyway, I think that this text is trying to say that the two statements $P \supset Q$ and $\sim Q$ together logically imply the statement $\sim P$.

Comment: Okay thank you! This was from a single page work sheet, very little context was given.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is called ["modus tollens"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modus_tollens).  The fomrula $P\supset Q$, in older work, means $P \rightarrow Q$.  I would state *modus tollens* as:
\begin{align}
\underline{P \rightarrow Q,\quad\sim Q}
\\
\sim P\qquad
\end{align}
It is a valid inference rule.

Comment: That makes some sense, but if super-set symbol is supposed to be interpreted as 'if-then' why then would '->' also be used? Why use two pieces of notion to express the same idea?

Comment: From the same text I just found this argument: '(P⊃Q), P → Q'
If are right about the way the super-set symbol should be interpreted then this is modus ponens.

Comment: If the syntactic implication operator $\supset$ known as ‘hook’ is being used, then likely $\rightarrow$ is being used to represent the semantics; i.e., if everything on the left hand side of $\rightarrow$ is true, we know that everything on the right hand side is as well.